# Unable to update user profile on Stack Overflow "This email address is already registered"

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am unable to update my user profile settings on Stack Overflow as I receive the following warning:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

I have read through some of the similar questions about having to merge accounts but I only appear to have one account. I tried logging in with Facebook and standard email but both appear to link to the same user number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah, sorry about that.

Back in October 2016, we imported CVs from Stack Overflow Careers into Stack Overflow user profiles themselves. At the time, we also attempted to match up Careers profiles with the right SO profiles... and we were *mostly* successful.

Long story short... you did have two accounts, because we mistakenly made another one for you in that transition period. I merged them together, so you should be able to edit your profile now without issues.

If anyone else is reading this and has the same problem, please [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and we will fix it for you.

Comment: 2020 knocking...  I'm finding this problem, was the `*` in *mostly\** successful ever consolidated?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure to solve this problem can be found in the following link: [How to merge user profiles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256689/how-to-merge-user-profiles)