# Sites saying I can't edit account because I must log in

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

So I wanted to edit my account like avatar icon and stuff, and when I did in Mathematics, It said "Sorry, but this E-Mail is already registered. If it is yours, please log in above. If you believe this is an issue, then request an Account Recovery". So the weird thing is that I was logged in already, because the only way I got to the edit profile screen was because I clicked on my profile icon in the top banner. It also was recognizing that it was my profile because it allowed me to attempt to edit it. Also, There was nothing related to logging in above the message that said I can log in above. So I checked below the message too, and I found nothing. I clicked the link to recover my account and it didn't do anything. I tried twice. So then I opened it in google and the same thing happened. The only site that says "Successfully edited Profile" is in Stack Overflow, but that is the only site that does not update my badges (See my other question on "Some sites showing badges achieved but not others"), So I am wondering what is going on.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299602/unable-to-update-user-profile-on-stack-overflow-this-email-address-is-already-r)?

Comment: Yes. That is what is happening to me, but I still have the issue. I have 5 accounts for the 5 sites I regularly go to, but I want to merge them into just one account. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was the same issue as the one described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299602/unable-to-update-user-profile-on-stack-overflow-this-email-address-is-already-r), I had a second separate account and the system was confusing that for this one.

As the developer said there:

> If anyone else is reading this and has the same problem, please [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and we will fix it for you.

I have contacted SE team via the contact form and they merged the accounts.

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: Yes. Also, I just lost 10 rep for something I'm not clear on. What might this be?

Comment: How did you get it fixed so fast? As for -10 if you see nothing in the profile page or the achievements drop down in top bar, it's most likely upvote that was undone.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I fixed it fast because I contacted the support team through the link you provided and they fixed it fast. I'd honestly would have loved to mark it as an answer but you posted it as a comment so I couldn't.

Comment: Cheers, I've edited the answer to make it more... neutral. You can accept your own answer in 48 hours, though you won't get points for it.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I appreciate helping to edit my posts as for some (particularly one user that I will not name in the act of courtesy) only say rude things that offend me and leave me feeling like I don't belong here, and then they down vote all of my posts. I don't get why some people act that way; but thank you for helping me because I am new to SE sites and have a lot to learn. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Anyone should be welcome here, and you can hop into [my chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/721/shadows-den) if you want to discuss this further without littering the post itself with comments. :)