# Cannot create new account on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: bug, user-accounts, askubuntu

I always get an error stating that I cannot create a new account on the [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) site. I am a member of several different Stack Exchange sites, but for some reason, I can't login to Ask Ubuntu. Apparently, I have previously linked my Stack Exchange account, given the fact that I see Ask Ubuntu in [my list of linked accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/6236403/jonathan-thoms?tab=accounts). I believe that there is potentially a bug exposed by something awry with my Stack Exchange account.

I have gotten the same apparently transient error for some months now. On the [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) site, I click "Join this community", followed by "Confirm new account". However, when I do this, I get the following error page message:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.askubuntu.com.

I'm asking my question on this site, and not on [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com), because I can't log in or create an account there.

How can I successfully login to the Ask Ubuntu community?

Comment: You [already have an account on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/465283/jonathan-thoms) Have you tried clearing your browser cookies and restarting your browser, or using another browser altogether. If that doesn't work you'll need to use the [contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) process.

Comment: Looks like you have two accounts that are somehow just slightly intermingled ([one](https://stackexchange.com/users/304434/jonathan-thoms) and [two](https://stackexchange.com/users/6236403/jonathan-thoms)). I suspect a merge will be required but it would be useful to know what you did in September which led to this state.

Comment: Can you try accessing [your Ask Ubuntu profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/465283/jonathan-thoms) now? You shouldn't need to "join this community" as your profiles should be linked.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. Now I'm able to log in. Do you know what happened? FYI, nothing that I knowingly did back in September. This has been an issue for me for several months, much earlier than September. Thank you so much for resolving. Now I can properly upvote questions and answers that help me. :-)

Comment: I don't know how it happened, no. I only know how I fixed it. :-) (And I only guessed September because that was the last time the _other_ account had successfully logged in.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Very grateful that I now have an account. btw, feel free to turn your comment into an answer. I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The network account <-> user profile relationship is, well, complicated.

I recently [resolved a similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393933/165455) for someone who had additional accounts that somehow got associated with the wrong e-mail address. That's not *exactly* what happened here, but it is potentially useful background and may share some underlying contributing factor.

In your case: You had two accounts at the network level, and the wrong account was associated with the lone Ask Ubuntu user.

**I've fixed that.**

Unfortunately, it is not obvious how or when this happened (read: it could happen again). The important part was getting you in again; I will circle back and try to understand this as time allows.