# StackExchange won't let me update my profile

Tags: support, profile-page

no matter what I do, whenever I try to save an update to my profile, I get the following message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
> This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

But I'm already logged in. How else could I get into edit profile page.
So I go through account recovery and reset my password.
Did it multiple times and I still get the message.

Could you PLEASE tell me how I can update my profile?

Comment: I think you better open a ticket via the [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) as this needs SE staff to diagnose.

Comment: On which of your SE sites are you trying to update? You can update it on other site, and it will change this on all sites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update user profile on Stack Overflow "This email address is already registered"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299602/unable-to-update-user-profile-on-stack-overflow-this-email-address-is-already-r)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ no each case is different, and Stack Overflow Careers is long dead, this has nothing to do with that old report.